# wxPython keeping a wx.Frame square?

Tags: wxpython

I'm wanting to keep a Frame square (like a chess board). It can be resized. Here is what I tried. It keeps the Frame square, but it won't decrease in size. It will only increase in size.

```
import wx

class MainWindow (wx.Frame):
    def __init__ (self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        self.Show()

    def OnSize (self, event):
        w,h = self.GetClientSize()
        size = max(w,h)
        self.SetClientSize((size,size))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    win = MainWindow()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I just tried this on OSX, wxPython version 2.8.12.1 and it works fine there, that is, I can both increase and decrease the window size.

Comment: Does it work for both dragging the corner and the sides? I double checked and it works if I drag from the corner, but not from the sides.

Comment: I don't seem to have an option to grab from the sides, just the lower right corner.

Comment: The problem is that `max(w, h)` will always return the largest number. So if you are decreasing the size horizontally, the vertical size will overrule the horizontal size. So ideally, you would want to know what changed in `OnSize`, so you can deduce what the user intent was (increase or decrease), and use `min`/`max` accordingly. One idea is to store the previous size on the frame, so you can compare the new and previous size.

Comment: Bouke's comment is the right answer, and should probably be promoted to be an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: I have tried what Bouke suggests when looking for the answer myself, but I did not get it to work properly :-/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Copied from my comment as suggested by RobinDunn)

The problem is that `max(w, h)` will always return the largest number. So if you are decreasing the size horizontally, the vertical size will overrule the horizontal size. So ideally, you would want to know what changed in `OnSize`, so you can deduce what the user intent was (increase or decrease), and use `min/max` accordingly. One idea is to store the previous size on the frame, so you can compare the new and previous size.

The idea is something like the code below. Note that it is still rough around the edges, but 
 it should give you a starting point.

```
import wx


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self._size = self.ClientSize
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        self.Show()

    def OnSize(self, event):
        if self._size[0] != self.ClientSize[0]:
            self._size = self.ClientSize[0], self.ClientSize[0]
        elif self._size[1] != self.ClientSize[1]:
            self._size = self.ClientSize[1], self.ClientSize[1]

        if self._size != self.ClientSize:
            self.ClientSize = self._size


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    win = MainWindow()
    app.MainLoop()
```